# Steps to follow for Assigning Multiple IP Address for AWS Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I am currently using EC2 Instances of Amazon. We are trying to deploy multiple sites with different IPs as Amazon has recently released to handle multiple IP Addresses.

Its very hard to find the proper steps to start with the Multiple IP Address for VPC Instance.

Is there a step by step guide to follow for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can always google'it :) but here ya go:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#MultipleIPReqs